# How to replace this svg that animates to just one that draws the polygon

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I'm sure this is an easy question for someone who knows `svg`, however, that's not me and I' converting an existing program that uses `svg` and don't have access to the original programmer to ask.

I have the following function that renders a polygon and every second, rotates it. I want it to just render the original polygon and stop. If I remove the `animateTranform` element completely, I get the vector, but not set to the position I want in degrees.  I can change the `to=` line to just include `+0` instead of `+360` but that seems strange.

I'd appreciate if someone could suggest how to make this simpler and non moving.  Thanks

```
export function SecondsArrow({deg}) {
    return <polygon points="25,26 25,22" className="Clock__seconds">

        <animateTransform
          attributeName="transform"
          begin="0s"
          dur="60s"
          type="rotate"
          from={`${deg} 25 25`}
          to={`${deg + 360} 25 25`}
          repeatCount="indefinite"
        />

    </polygon>
}
```

Comment: I can see no reason why removing the `<animateTransform>` element should not work as expected. Did you per chance also remove the `</polygon>` closing tag? Also, since the polygon actually is only a line, is there a CSS rule somewhere that defines a `stroke`?

Comment: Also, if you want to maintain the direction the arrow points at to be `deg`, include a `transform="\`rotate(${deg} 25 25)\`"` attribute with the polygon.

Comment: @stroke, you are right in that it doe show but does not show with the initial transform (I mean to say it did no show what I wanted).  I'm wanting it to show at the from position only and do not transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to maintain the direction the arrow points at to be `deg`, include a `transform="rotate(${deg} 25 25)"` attribute with the polygon.

```
export function SecondsArrow({deg}) {
    return <polygon
      points="25,26 25,22"
      transform={`rotate(${deg} 25 25)`}
      className="Clock__seconds">
    />
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll check this when I get home

Comment: Thanks @ccprog. You back ticks are not quite right so I posted the correction below my question. If you fix your answer I'll remove the answer from my question, but probably not worth the effort.

Comment: I should have guessed, but since you never said which framework this was from, I extrapolated...poorly.